# Question about search results

Tags: discussion, search

Search Query

> "jqGrid: dataurl" = 302 results
>   "jqGrid dataurl" (removed colon) =
>   198 results

Why are there fewer results for the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jqGrid:` is an invalid search operator, and since it's invalid, it's simply being removed.  So now the question becomes:

> "dataurl" = 302 results 
>   "jqGrid dataurl" (removed colon) = 198 results

Why are there fewer results for the second query?

With the obvious answer being, "because it's making a more specific query".